# Exception Reason: -[NSParagraphStyle bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16fe2130

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, dsym, nsparagraphstyle

I have an iOS that crash sometimes because of "Exception Reason: -[NSParagraphStyle bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16fe2130".

The Crash log looks like:

```
0 CoreFoundation 0x2b520477 <redacted> + 150
1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x3941bc8b objc_exception_throw + 38
2 CoreFoundation 0x2b525879 <redacted> + 0
3 CoreFoundation 0x2b523797 <redacted> + 714
4 CoreFoundation 0x2b455008 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 24
5 CoreGraphics 0x2b7814c3 CGGradientGetFunction + 42
6 CoreGraphics 0x2b7813ef CGContextDrawLinearGradient + 94
7 MPK aFON 0x0018622b MPK aFON + 573995
8 UIKit 0x2eab63f1 <redacted> + 400
9 QuartzCore 0x2e48f04d <redacted> + 228
10 QuartzCore 0x2e478a8b <redacted> + 2070
11 QuartzCore 0x2e55bc09 <redacted> + 52
12 QuartzCore 0x2e478269 <redacted> + 88
13 QuartzCore 0x2e477f19 <redacted> + 1160
14 QuartzCore 0x2e45c3d9 <redacted> + 200
15 QuartzCore 0x2e45c09d <redacted> + 24
16 QuartzCore 0x2e45ba71 <redacted> + 224
17 QuartzCore 0x2e45b875 <redacted> + 324
18 UIKit 0x2ea3c203 <redacted> + 1442
19 CoreFoundation 0x2b4e6fbf <redacted> + 14
20 CoreFoundation 0x2b4e63cf <redacted> + 218
21 CoreFoundation 0x2b4e4a35 <redacted> + 772
22 CoreFoundation 0x2b4323b1 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 476
23 CoreFoundation 0x2b4321c3 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
24 GraphicsServices 0x32a19201 GSEventRunModal + 136
25 UIKit 0x2ea9c43d UIApplicationMain + 1440
26 MPK aFON 0x000fee3f MPK aFON + 20031
27 libdyld.dylib 0x399a7aaf <redacted> + 2
```

I have the dSYM file for the app and for the "0x000fee3f" I got:

```
dSYM for Apps adrianmaftei$ dwarfdump --lookup 0x000fee3f app.app201.dSYM
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 File: app.app201.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/App (armv7)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Looking up address: 0x00000000000fee3f in .debug_info... found!

0x002033a1: Compile Unit: length = 0x000093d7  version = 0x0002  abbr_offset = 0x00000000  addr_size = 0x04  (next CU at 0x0020c77c)

0x002033ac: TAG_compile_unit [1] *
             AT_producer( "Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.54) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)" )
             AT_language( DW_LANG_ObjC )
             AT_name( "/Users/adrianmaftei/Documents/Work/aFON/Classes/AfonLFManager.m" )
             AT_stmt_list( 0x000611ac )
             AT_comp_dir( "/Users/adrianmaftei/Documents/Work/aFON" )
             AT_APPLE_optimized( 0x01 )
             AT_APPLE_major_runtime_vers( 0x02 )
             AT_low_pc( 0x000fec38 )

0x00204b37:     TAG_subprogram [10] *
                 AT_name( "-[AfonLFManager parseColorInfo]" )
                 AT_decl_file( "/Users/adrianmaftei/Documents/Work/aFON/Classes/AfonLFManager.m" )
                 AT_decl_line( 57 )
                 AT_prototyped( 0x01 )
                 AT_APPLE_isa( 0x01 )
                 AT_accessibility( DW_ACCESS_public )
                 AT_low_pc( 0x000fed58 )
                 AT_high_pc( 0x000feee2 )
                 AT_frame_base( r7 )
                 AT_object_pointer( {0x00204b4f} )

0x00204b76:         TAG_lexical_block [13] *
                     AT_ranges( 0x0000fa38
                        [0x000fed96 - 0x000feebc)
                        [0x000feec6 - 0x000feed2)
                         End )

0x00204b7b:             TAG_lexical_block [13] *
                         AT_ranges( 0x0000fa50
                            [0x000fed9e - 0x000feebc)
                            [0x000feec6 - 0x000feed2)
                             End )

0x00204b8f:                 TAG_lexical_block [13] *
                             AT_ranges( 0x0000fa68
                                [0x000fedb0 - 0x000feebc)
                                [0x000feec6 - 0x000feed2)
                                 End )

0x00204b94:                     TAG_lexical_block [13] *
                                 AT_ranges( 0x0000fa80
                                    [0x000fedb8 - 0x000feebc)
                                    [0x000feec6 - 0x000feed2)
                                     End )

0x00204b99:                         TAG_lexical_block [13] *
                                     AT_ranges( 0x0000fa98
                                        [0x000fedb8 - 0x000feebc)
                                        [0x000feec6 - 0x000feed2)
                                         End )

0x00204ba9:                             TAG_lexical_block [13] *
                                         AT_ranges( 0x0000fab0
                                            [0x000fedb8 - 0x000feebc)
                                            [0x000feec6 - 0x000feeca)
                                             End )
Line table dir : '/Users/adrianmaftei/Documents/Work/aFON/Classes'
Line table file: 'AfonLFManager.m' line 64, column 0 with start address 0x00000000000fee10

Looking up address: 0x00000000000fee3f in .debug_frame... found!

0x0000d8f0: FDE
        length: 0x0000000c
   CIE_pointer: 0x00000000
    start_addr: 0x000fed58 -[AfonLFManager parseColorInfo]
    range_size: 0x0000018a (end_addr = 0x000feee2)
  Instructions: 0x000fed58: CFA=4294967295+4294967295
```

Do you have any ideas about how can I fix the issue?

Update:
The code for parseColorInfo is:

```
-(void)parseColorInfo{

TBXML *tbxml = [TBXML tbxmlWithXMLString:xmlContent];
if (tbxml){
    TBXMLElement *root = tbxml.rootXMLElement;
    if (root){
        for (int i=0; i<8; i++){
            TBXMLElement *dp = [TBXML childElementNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"color%d", i+1] parentElement:root];
            if (dp) {
                if( i < [colors count] ) {
                    UIColor *color = [colors objectAtIndex:i];
                    if( [TBXML textForElement:dp] ) {
                        color = [self colorFromHexString:[TBXML textForElement:dp]];
                        if( color )
                            [colors setObject:color atIndexedSubscript:i];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
- (UIColor *)colorFromHexString:(NSString *)hexString {
unsigned rgbValue = 0;
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:hexString];
if( scanner ) {
    [scanner setScanLocation:1]; // bypass '#' character
    [scanner scanHexInt:&rgbValue];
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16)/255.0 green:((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8)/255.0 blue:(rgbValue & 0xFF)/255.0 alpha:1.0];
}
return nil;
```

}

Comment: Study what "unrecognized selector" means.

Comment: Despite posting plenty of information (well done for that), it's not very useful.  For a start you need a symbolicated stacktrace; something that you would find useful as it tells you where the crash occurred.  If you want help from this site, you're then going to have to provide relevant code fragments as well.  As it stands there is nothing anyone can do to help (start with `[AfonLFManager parseColorInfo]`).

Comment: Thanks for comments, I updated the question to include the parseColorInfo method. I know what "unrecognized selector" means, but  I don't use directly in code [NSParagraphStyle bytes].